# Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Tags: php, reference, dompdf

`How to clear this problems for dompdf file  so please help me.`

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

```
//Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$html  = $this->load->view('mobileuserprint',$customers,true);
$domdpf = new Dompdf();
$domdpf->loadHtml($html);
$domdpf->setPaper('A4','landscape');
$domdpf->render();
```

Comment: What's with the dots?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting and what code do you have before you get to what you posted? From the title of your question it is obvious that something is sending output to the browser before this point.

Comment: this given code for html to pdf converted code already using successfully but now some files using (Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent) this error accuired so help me how to clear this error

Comment: yes,#Dave the showing error is Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent.how to clear this error tell me im confused

Comment: hi any one pls how to slove this problem

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
 
 //Reference the Dompdf namespace
 use Dompdf\Dompdf;
 
 $html  = $this->load->view('mobileuserprint',$customers,true);
 //if(headers_sent()) { print $html; die; }
 
 $domdpf = new Dompdf();
 $domdpf->loadHtml($html);
 $domdpf->setPaper('A4','landscape');
 $domdpf->render();
 
 $domdpf->stream("MobileuserprintList.pdf",array("Attachment" => false));
 exit();